# enum type, advancing to next level

Tags: java, enums

This code is not working, it says it needs assignment of operator expression. Why is that? Can you help me out?

```
enum Skill { ROOKIE, ADVANCED, EXPERT;

    public Skill getNext() {
        if (this.ordinal() < Skill.values().length - 1); 

        else { Skill.values() [this.ordinal() + 1];
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Can you fix it for me?" No. We can help you, not fix it for you.

Comment: could you help me make it work?

Comment: You haven't said what's wrong with it. "This code is not working" gives us nothing to work with. If you want help, you need to give us enough information so that we can actually do that.

Comment: Protip: If you want help on StackOverflow, make your question and code clear, well formatted, grammatically correct, and easy to read. Right now I'm trying to understand what your code is supposed to do...

Comment: We could, but looks like you need to review Java basics. For example, a method **must** return something from all the paths it has.

Comment: @AnubianNoob OP wants that that this `getNext` method returns `ADVANCED` when is called from `ROOKIE`, returns `EXPERT` when called from `ADVANCED`, and on and on (in case of more values), and in the end it should return `null` if it's at the maximum level.

Comment: You should avoid the usage of the [`ordinal()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal()) method.

Comment: simple `if (..) {return   Skill.values() [this.ordinal() + 1];} else{return null;}`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza that is correct.

Comment: @BheshGurung Why should I avoid using ordinal() method?

Comment: @user3482500 use of the ordinal method is frowned upon. Instead, give each item in the enum a int value. it makes your code more readable and easier to maintain.

Comment: Why so many downvotes? Sure it's not a great question, but it is valid (right)?

Comment: @user3482500 Advice : use `Enum.values()` with caution because it creates a new array each time you call it. You should better call it once for all and store the result somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. It will return the next difficulty level, or null if it is at the highest.

```
if (this.ordinal() < Skill.values().length - 1) {
    return Skil.values()[this.ordinal()+1];
} else {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Oops sorry. That was a type.

Comment: Always use braces `{}` when working with block of codes inside `if-else` or `for` statements, even if only contains a single statement.

Comment: +1 @LuiggiMendoza because a developer who has to maintain the code might not think about it.

Comment: I shouldn't copy/paste OP code but retype it instead to catch these errors :)

Comment: So if I would want to use the method of assigning int to each enum value would I then use increment to advance to next level?